# What is the stripe webhook event for all types of incoming payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

There is [a ton of different stripe webhook event types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types), but I can't seem to find the one I'm looking for.

Of the list, these three seem most applicable:

```
charge.succeeded: Occurs whenever a new charge is created and is successful.

invoice.payment_succeeded: Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt succeeds.

order.payment_succeeded: Occurs whenever an order payment attempt succeeds.

transfer.paid: Occurs after a transfer is paid. For Instant Payouts, the event will be sent on the next business day, although the funds should be received well beforehand.
```

But I'm not sure if there's any overlap between these, and have a hard time believing there isn't one, all encompassing, you-just-got-paid webhook event.

Do I have to create webhooks for all of these?  Or is there a webhook event that does that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charge.succeeded` will fire every time one of your customers is successfully charged. The others are for more specific types of situations, but that one will fire for a successful payment in general.